# dhcpd , How to hand out POSIX Timezone

Tags: dhcp, timezone

We have a Cisco switch which logs this each time it gets its IP via DHCP:

```
WARN DHCPCLIENT[DHCP Client Task]: dhcp_support.c(1018)  1451 %% Posix Timezone Information is not obtained  from the server.
```

How can we configure dhcpd (standard dhcpd running on RHEL 6.1) to hand out that info ? (This is seemingly not the `option time-offset` , as that's already set)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the switch expect options described in [RFC 4833 “Timezone Options for DHCP”](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4833); most likely the option 100, TZ POSIX String. This option first needs to be defined in dhcpd.conf:

```
option tz-posix-string code 100 = string;
```

After the definition statement the option can be set just like a standard option known to dhcpd:

```
option tz-posix-string "EST5EDT4,M3.2.0/02:00,M11.1.0/02:00";
```

Comment: We were having a similar issue with iLO, using the 101 code tzdb-string with "EST5EDT" worked for us.